# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la separación de datos que se encuentran en una tabla y en un mismo campo?

Tags: postgresql, datatables, sql

Estoy realizando unos ajustes de denominacion para mi trabajo y me encuentro con un conflicto en leguaje SQL, tengo el departamento y la ciudad en un mismo campo y los requiero separar pero es una tabla de 6000 registros, eh estado investigando como puedo hacerlo pero no doy con la idea, la idea es que se separe el departamento, (un ejemplo separar "MAICAO" de "LA GUAJIRA" y almacenarlo en otro campo) Espero me puedan ayudar el leguaje es SQL y el motor es Postgre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando la siguiente consulta...

```
SELECT columna28, STRING_SPLIT(columna28, '/', 1), STRING_SPLIT(columna28, '/', 2) FROM tabla;
```

Comment: Gracias compa, pero no me funciona la sintaxis, no se que puede ser

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) para dividir una columna en múltiples, en función de un patrón regular, por ejemplo:

```
select a[1] as Parte1, 
       a[2] as Parte2
       from (
            select string_to_array(columna28, '/')
                   from tabla
       ) as dt(a))
```